# Rails Activerecord/Postgres time format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, time, rails-activerecord

I am working on a Rails project using a Postgres database.  For one of my models, I have a time column, called (cleverly) time.  When I created the model, I set the data type for this column as 'time', with the (perhaps incorrect) understanding that this data type was for storing time only, no date.

```
t.time :time
```

However, when I submit data to the model, the time is correct but prefixed by an incorrect date:

```
time: "2000-01-01 16:57:19"
```

I just want the column to store the time (like '16:57:19'). Is 'time' the correct data type to use?  Or is there some other way I should handle this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Rails should map the `time` type to the Postgres time type. Are you sure you are using postgres and not sqlite for the development environment?

Comment: @max: The OP isn't mapping anything, ActiveRecord is. See below.

Comment: Yes - I set it up to use Postgres in development

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that there is no time-of-day class in Ruby or Rails. All the time classes are dates or timestamps (i.e. date plus time of day).

Inside the database it will be a [`time`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE) (without timezone) column and it will behave properly inside the database. However, once the time gets into Ruby, ActiveRecord will add a date component because there is no plain time-of-day class available, it just happens to use 2000-01-01 as the date.

Everything will be fine inside the database but you'll have to exercise a little bit of caution to ignore the date component when you're outside the database in Rails.

Comment: Ok that's interesting, thank you.  I didn't know that.